# eth0:<name> interfaces in Linux

Tags: linux

I have a server which shows following three "secondary" IPv4 addresses in `ip addr show` output under physical interface `eth0` section:

```
inet 10.10.1.26/32 scope global eth0:vpn
inet 10.10.1.19/32 scope global eth0:webmail
inet 10.10.1.20/32 scope global eth0:wiki
```

Those `eth0:vpn`, `eth0:webmail` and `eth0:wiki` interfaces are not seen in `ip link show` output as VLAN-interfaces(for example `eth0.123`) would. What are those `eth0:vpn`, `eth0:webmail` and `eth0:wiki` interfaces?

Comment: Those are interface aliases.  Basically they allow a single machine to have more than one IP in the same network.  Those are useful in many situations, such as running an authoritative DNS resolver on an IP and a recursive one on a different IP, or temporarily moving services to a different machine without reconfiguring an entire LAN when a main server crashes.

Comment: @lcd047 I see. Am I correct that basically those "interface aliases" are like "secondary addresses" in Cisco IOS terminology, i.e. simply allow one interface to have more than one IP address? And still, what is the reason for those labels `eth0:vpn`, `eth0:webmail` and `eth0:wiki`?

Comment: _Am I correct that basically those "interface aliases" are like "secondary addresses" in Cisco IOS terminology_ - Yes, exactly like that. _And still, what is the reason for those labels `eth0:vpn`, `eth0:webmail` and `eth0:wiki`?_ - They are just labels assigned by the sysadmin.  I suppose the point is to make it easier to tell which service is associated to which alias.  There isn't anything special (AFAICT) about the names themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from my comments above:

Those are interface aliases. Basically they allow a single machine to have more than one IP in the same network. Those are useful in many situations, such as running an authoritative DNS resolver on an IP and a recursive one on a different IP, or temporarily moving services to a different machine without reconfiguring an entire LAN when a main server crashes.

> Am I correct that basically those "interface aliases" are like "secondary addresses" in Cisco IOS terminology

Yes, exactly like that.

> And still, what is the reason for those labels `eth0:vpn`, `eth0:webmail` and `eth0:wiki`?

They are just labels assigned by the sysadmin. I suppose the point is to make it easier to tell which service is associated to which alias. There isn't anything special (AFAICT) about the names themselves.